# How to make a mechanical machine that can produce a physical drawing of the displacement-versus-time graph of a simple harmonic motion

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator, home-experiment

I am still in high school so please present only concepts, intuitions and algebra-based solutions.

I propose that I create a tall pendulum with a dense ball (maybe made of rocks and cement) and a light spring with low spring constant attached to the ball. The spring connects to a piece of graphite or chalk to write out the equation. (on a rotating platform)

I want to ask two things:

1. Is my setup feasible and why?
2. What setup should I do a produce the graph?
3. Should I move this question to Engineering SE?

Comment: You might take inspiration from [this article](http://practicalphysics.org/broomstick-pendulum-sinusoidal-motion.html)

Answer (score 1):

It could work. You could run in to at least four problems. First, if it's a pendulum attached to a spring, you need to account for the fact that both the pendulum and the spring supply a force that affect the frequency of the swing. Though you can account for that effect, it seems to be beyond high school level as it is a slightly advanced first year college level problem. Second, keeping the graphite in contact with the rotating platform as the pendulum changes its height isn't trivial. It's possible, but not easy. Third, drawing a graph along a rotating platform like that will distort the graph, depending on the radius of the disk. Fourth, the rotating disk is going to exert a force on the pendulum via the graphite, altering the motion.

Here's what I would recommend instead: fight some way to have a weighted cart that moves back and forth on a track. Make sure the cart still moves freely when it feels a sideways force. Attach the cart to a spring, and let it oscillate on the track. On the bottom of the cart, place a piece of graphite (don't use chalk - too much friction) or a pen sticking out from the bottom of the cart onto a piece of paper. The paper should be on some kind of conveyor belt, rotating drum, or just pull it along underneath the track, so it moves sideways under the cart as it oscillates.

Now, no matter what setup you choose, you'll find that the oscillations will die down with time due to damping. You can prevent this if you add a driver to the end of the spring not attached to the cart. The driver, if you tune it correctly, will continuously add energy to the cart, allowing you to maintain a constant oscillation. You'll need to have the driver's force (amplitude) turned low if you want to drive the cart at the natural frequency. Adding a driver isn't essential, though, since driven harmonic motion is technically another topic.